# How to make dialog show multiple line?

Tags: java, dialog

I am trying to make dialog show the all answers in one dialog but in multiple lines and I got no idea because after I add `\n` it show `\n` in the line too here is my code (I just deleted `\n` line as it doesn't work at all)

```java
Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);

int firstnumber= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the first number"));


int secondnumber= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the second number"));

int minus= firstnumber - secondnumber;
int sum= firstnumber + secondnumber;  //sum the first number and second number
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"" + firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + sum + ""+firstnumber+"-"+secondnumber+"="+minus,  "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use html tag

```
<br>
```

Comment: but html only work with a one long sentence right?  because my code it not a sentence?

Comment: this is a long sentence: `"" + firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + sum + "<br/>"+firstnumber+"-"+secondnumber+"="+minus`

Comment: sorry for bothering,  this is how it look:
[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/2hwza0w.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: so I am sorry this is not working, could you try it please without / like `"" + firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + sum + "<br>"+firstnumber+"-"+secondnumber+"="+minus`

Comment: I have founded another solution try `\n\r` instead of `\n`

Comment: awesome!! it's working now, i used the \n\r in the "" in front of the firstnumber ;) thank again for helping me out!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the text needs to be in a multiline container, such as JTextArea, otherwise it's just interpreted as plain text.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html for implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Then type newline in the string to add a newline.